# Prove a subset of $C[-1,1]$ is a closed subspace.

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

> Consider $C[-1,1]$ under the sup-norm. Let $$X= \{f\in C[-1,1]:\int_{-1}^{0}f=\int_{0}^{1}f=0\},$$
> Prove $X$ is a closed subspace of $C[-1,1]$

My attempt:

It is trivial to prove $X$ is a subspace. To prove $X$ is closed: consider a sequence of function $\{f_k\}$in $X$ that converges to $f$ in $C[-1,1]$. Then $\forall \epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $$\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$$  for $n,m\geq N$, and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert_{\infty}=\lVert\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n-f_m\rVert_{\infty}=\lVert f-f_m\rVert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$$
by continuity of the sup-norm. By the property of $X$:$$\int_{-1}^{0}f-f_m\leq\int_{-1}^{0}\vert f-f_m \vert\leq \int_{-1}^{0}\lVert f-f_m\rVert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$$ Then $-\epsilon\leq\int_{-1}^{0}f\leq\epsilon$ since $\int_{-1}^{0}f_m=0$. We conclude $\int_{-1}^{0}f=0 $ and similarly $\int_{0}^{1}f=0$. As $\{f_k\}$ are continuous functions uniformly converges to $f$, $f$ is continuous.

Therefore, $f\in X$ and $X$ is a closed subspace in $C[-1,1]$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks great to me!

Comment: Hi, can I say $\lVert f-f_m\rVert_{\infty}\leq\epsilon$ directly without showing the use of continuity of sup-norm? This part might be redundant.

Comment: Yes that was a curious thing to me. $f_n \to f$ $\implies$ $\|f_n - f\| \le \epsilon$ for all $n$ suff large. It is not wrong either though!

Comment: There’s a shorter prove, by the way. $X$ is an intersection of kernels of two bounded linear functionals.